Can I still publish maui .net 7 in visual studio for mac?
I am using Visual Studio for Mac and I know that .net 7 and visual studio for mac is out of support already.
Archive for publishing is missing in the menu of maui project properties.
If I will be using Vs Code, is it possible to publish it in .net 7?
Tried to install vs code and open the .net 7 maui project but im having a lot of error.

NET7 will not receive updates anymore, including security updates, but it does not cease to exist.

dotnet --list-sdks
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/(.net 9 version)
In my case there's .net 9 installed.
I uninstall .net 9 and Archive for Publishing appears again.
